# Кодировка MSSQL при воводе PHP

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

Извиняюсь, за глупый вопрос, знаю что тема изжевана сто тысяч раз, но у себя не могу найти ошибку. В mysql таких проблем не испытаваю, mssql выбор не мой, но реализовать нужно.
Подскажите, что делаю не так, есть файл config.php, который стандартно подключаю ко всем скриптам.
Устанавливаю кодировку запросом так

```
sqlsrv_query($conn,'set names cp1251');
```

или так :

```
sqlsrv_query($conn,'SET NAMES utf8');
```

где $conn параметры соединения с сервером. Но оба варианта не помогают.
Все бы хорошо, но при выводе из MSSQL в браузер выводятся знаки вопроса, вместо кирилицы.
Нагуглил, что необходимо указывать в MSSQL каджому столбцу

```
COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
```

Собственно всем столбцам проставил, но знаки вопроса при выводе не исчезают.

Comment: А тип столбцов в таблице, видимо, `varchar`? Поменяйте на `nvarchar`.

Comment: поменял на nvarchar - не помогло,
как подсказали ниже, на сохранение файлов стал использовать 
$var = iconv('UTF-8','windows-1251',$_GET['project_manager']);
и далее отдаю $var в запрос, в бд вставляется вроде правильно, знаков вопроса нет, но на выводе все теже знаки ???.
Пробую на запросе вывода, делать наоборот:
$var = iconv('windows-1251','UTF-8',$arr['project_manager']); в ответе получаю - Р¤РРћР¤РРћ  а на странице это все равно знаки ???.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSSQL сервер хранит данные в windows-1251, поэтому если у вас файл php находиться в кодировке utf-8, то при вставке в бд вам нужно менять кодировку ваших переменных c utf-8 на  windows-1251 с помощью функции iconv. Так же вам нужно будет менять кодировку в обратном направлении при получении данных из БД. Как вариант можно поменять кодировку php файла, но скорее всего это обернется проблемами так как сейчас все в вебе направлено на utf-8.

Comment: на сохранение файлов стал использовать $var = iconv('UTF-8','windows-1251',$_GET['project_manager']); и далее отдаю $var в запрос, в бд вставляется вроде правильно, знаков вопроса нет, но на выводе все теже знаки ???. Пробую на запросе вывода, делать наоборот: $var = iconv('windows-1251','UTF-8',$arr['project_manager']); в ответе получаю - Р¤РРћР¤РРћ а на странице это все равно знаки ???.

Comment: в notepade++ посмотрите в какой кодировке у вас страница, если не в utf-8 то преобразуйте в utf-8 без bom

Comment: спасибо большое!